# Joda Time - Go back 1 year, adjusting for specific day-of-week

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to go 1 year back with joda time, but I don't want to go from 15 February 2010 to 15 February 2009 but rather, if 15 Februari 2010 is a Monday for example, then I want to get to the closest Monday of 2009.

At the moment I am using this:

```
int dayNumber = Integer.parseInt(iDate.dayOfWeek().getAsString());

if(dayNumber == 1) { // start of week
    println(iDate.plusYears(-1).plusDays(1).dayOfWeek().getAsString());
}
```

Which works fine for now but there is probably safer way that allows you to go back easily 5 years for example.

Comment: So... you _don't_ want to go 1 year back then.

Comment: The adjustment is different for leap years.

Comment: What is your definition of "closest (day of the week)?" Given 2010-02-15 as input, you expect 2009-02-16 as output. What do you expect the output to be for input 2012-02-15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Joda Time methods to go back 1 year and then have a little `switch` statement that moves it to the appropriate day.  Can't tell if you want to go to monday or not from your question.  Doing your own calculations is going to miss important things like leap years as @Klas pointed out.

```
iDate = iDate.minusYears(1);
switch (iDate.getDayOfWeek()) {
    case 1:
        // monday so no change
        break;
    case 2:
        iDate = iDate.minusDays(1);
        break;
    case 3:
        iDate = iDate.minusDays(2);
        break;
    ...
}
```

If you want to get fancy you can build a little grid to speed it up.

```
// days in joda time are 1 based so 0 won't be used here
private static final int[] daysShift = new int[] = {0, 0, -1, -2, -3, 3, 2, 1};
...
iDate = iDate.minusYears(1);
// based on the current day, shift us by a certain number of days, + or -
iDate.plusDays(daysShift[iDate.getDayOfWeek()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, [`#getAsString()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/field/AbstractReadableInstantFieldProperty.html#getAsString%28%29)

> returns the value converted to a `String` using `Integer.toString`

so it's rather silly to convert to a string, and then immediately convert back:

```
int dayNumber = iDate.dayOfWeek().get();
// or
int dayNumber = iDate.getDayOfWeek();
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
         .minusYears( 1 )
         .previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )
```

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## Year ago

The java.time classes can do math.

```
LocalDate yearAgo = today.minusYears( 1 ) ;
```

## Day of week

Determine today’s day-of-week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

To adjust into different date-time values, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation. One for your purpose is found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
LocalDate previousOrSameDay = yearAgo.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( dow ) ;
```

Or get the following day-of-week.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameDay = yearAgo.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( dow ) ;
```

You need to define your rules for going to next or previous.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > previous = EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY ) ;  // Collect Mon, Tue, Wed, and Thu.
Set< DayOfWeek > next = EnumSet.complementOf​( previous) ;  // Collect Fri, Sat, Sun.
```

Then test your day-of-week.

```
LocalDate ld ;
if( previous.contains( dow ) ) {
    ld = yearAgo.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( dow ) ;
} else if ( next.contains( dow ) ) {
    ld = yearAgo.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( dow ) ;
} else {
    // Handle unexpected error.
    System.out.println( "Unexpectedly reached IF-ELSE for day-of-week: " + dow ) ;
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).